# when I use use pipe when the command is stored in a string, the pipe will be recognized as '|', why?

Tags: bash

I excute bash shell like this

```
cmd="cat tmp1.list tmp2.list | sort > tmp3.list"
$cmd
```

the result is

```
sdas
qqq
cat: |: No such file or directory
cat: sort: No such file or directory
cat: >: No such file or directory
cat: tmp3.list: No such file or directory
enter code here
```

I konw 'eval' can work
but I want to know why it can't

Comment: This is [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050): "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) discussing alternatives to storing code inside strings. In terms of *why* this is a problem -- to summarize from [The Bash Parser](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser), the parsing steps are:

1. **Read data to execute.**
2. **Process quotes.**
3. **Split the read data into commands.** This is where `;`, `&`, etc. are given semantic meaning.
4. **Parse special operators.** This is where `|`, `>`, etc. are given special meaning.
5. **Perform expansions.** This is where `$cmd` is replaced with the variable's value.
6. **Split the command into a command name and arguments.** This is where the value is split into words.
7. **Execute the command.**

In summary, `|` and `>` are processed in steps 3 and 4, whereas the value of `$cmd` is only substituted in step 5 (and prepared in step 6).

Answer (score 1):

Operator precedence happen before variable substitution.

For example :

```
$cmd | cat
```

The command is splitted

```
$cmd -> | -> cat
```

$cmd will be executed, then piped to cat

Then, your $cmd is replaced, but executed as a single command. It does not open a subshell for it. 
So the first command is executed, and everything else is added as an argument to it.

Comment: This is intentional and necessary -- if it were the other way around it would be nearly impossible to write secure code handling untrusted data in bash.

Answer (score 0):

maybe what you need is a function

```
function cmd {
    cat tmp1.list tmp2.list | sort > tmp3.list
}

cmd
```

also aliases works string with but they used in interactive shell.

Comment: The POSIX-compliant function declaration syntax, btw, is `cmd() {` -- using the `function` keyword makes your code incompatible with baseline-POSIX shells but adds no compensating benefit.

Comment: Also, the question is "why?", not "what should I do instead?"

Comment: the advantage of using `function` is if `cmd` is already defined `cmd() {`  will fail

Comment: Not if `cmd` is already defined as a function, or if it's already an external command. Maybe if it's an alias, but if you have an alias conflicting with your function you have bigger problems.

Comment: Moreover, you're still leaving that conflicting alias in place, so to let the function declaration *work* means you're setting up bigger issues down the road.

Comment: in fact it's no more the case with my actual bash version, but when i worked with ksh, I used `cmd() {` syntax and someone told me I should use the other for this reason

Comment: It's not true with ksh93u+ (the version I most conveniently have on hand to test) either.